# Google Speech to Text API Undefined Method

Tags: ruby, api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to learn how to use the google speech to text API but I'm getting an undefined method error when running the code. The code is taken from google cloud client library to use. I'm not sure how to fix the error.
Error: : undefined method alternatives for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
#use gem install google-cloud-speech

require "google/cloud/speech"


speech = Google::Cloud::Speech.speech


file_name = "file_path"


audio_file = File.binread file_name


config = { encoding:          :LINEAR16,
       sample_rate_hertz: 16_000,
       language_code:     "en-US" }
audio  = { content: audio_file }


response = speech.recognize config: config, audio: audio

results = response.results

results.first.alternatives.each do |alternatives|
puts "Transcription: #{alternatives.transcript}"
  end
```

Comment: There is no first result - which implies there are no results. This might not be an error; maybe it just couldn’t get anything from your audio file. Is there a demo audio file you can use which you know google can get results from?

Comment: Perhaps you have followed this documentation (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-ruby). Have you used the provided sample file as well? Or did you use a different one?

I tried to run this code in the GCP console but did not encounter the error. May I know have you run this code in a different environment?

Comment: @TomHarvey I used an audio file that I created using the google text to speech API and used its file path. I also tried my own recording as well.

Comment: @RallyH Did you just copy paste the provided code from that documentation and ran it? I did the same thing but I copied it into vs code and ran it using the terminal. I also had my own voice recording file that I used for the path.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to replicate your issue and I was able to successfully execute the code and other examples from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/samples). In addition, since you stated that you are learning how to use the Speech to Text API from Google, I will describe the steps I took.

It seems that you have taken the code from the [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-speech/samples/speech_samples.rb). However, you do not have the first lines and the last lines of the code, which respectively define transcription method and the call to execute it. For this reason, when you execute your code there is no call to any method and neither to the Speech-to-Text API. Your code should be as follows:

```
def speech_sync_recognize audio_file_path: nil
  # [START speech_transcribe_sync]
  # audio_file_path = "Path to file on which to perform speech recognition"

  require "google/cloud/speech"

  speech = Google::Cloud::Speech.speech

  # [START speech_ruby_migration_sync_response]
  audio_file = File.binread audio_file_path
  config     = { encoding:          :LINEAR16,
                 sample_rate_hertz: 16_000,
                 language_code:     "en-US" }
  audio      = { content: audio_file }

  response = speech.recognize config: config, audio: audio

  results = response.results

  alternatives = results.first.alternatives
  alternatives.each do |alternative|
    puts "Transcription: #{alternative.transcript}"
  end
  # [END speech_ruby_migration_sync_response]
  # [END speech_transcribe_sync]
end

if $PROGRAM_NAME == __FILE__
  command = ARGV.shift

#I have added this part in order to use a command after to define which method to call within the code.
  case command
  when "recognize"
    speech_sync_recognize audio_file_path: ARGV.first

  end
end
```

And in order to run the sample,

```
bundle exec ruby speech_samples.rb
```

Notice the argument `recognize` which describes which method to execute from the code. In the above case, there is just one. However,using arguments in the call  is very useful when there other methods available to call within the code.

Furthermore, I will describe the steps I took in order to execute the code properly. I have followed the steps described [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-speech/samples),

1. I have have ran the code from Cloud Shell. However the `speech.googleapis.com`  does not support end user authentication from Cloud Shell. For this reason, I have given the `Service Account Token Creator` from [IAM Console](https://cloud.google.com/iam) to my user, so I could impersonate a Service Account and call the API.
2. Export your `project_id` to a environment variable such as `export GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT="YOUR-PROJECT-ID"`.
3. Download the [Gemfile](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-speech/samples/Gemfile) file from the documentation and run the command: `bundle install`
4. Copy the code [speech_samples.rb](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-speech/samples/speech_samples.rb) to your environment.
5. Copy your file path to  the variable `audio_file_path` and un-comment it. Notice that there will be many `audio_file_path` local variables, each one for a specific method. In my case, I copied the path only to the variable in the first function, **`audio_file_path = "home/alex/audio.wav"`**.
6. Pay attention that each function has a specific configured argument (*from line 437 onward*). In my case, I wanted to use the `recognize` one.
7. Run the sample code with `bundle exec ruby speech_samples.rb recognize`.
8. Check your environment for a new directory called `results`. Then inspect the outputs.
9. Please, do not forget to copy your file path to all the functions you will be calling with the proper arguments.

**UPDATE:**

As I mentioned in the comment section, the code I shared above is part of the file `speech_samples.rb` which contains various examples of functions that calls the Speech-To-Text API. In my case, I just used part of the sample, which I pasted above.

Regarding the link you shared, there is a button to the GitHub source repo for the code, which is the same as the one with the example I used. Notice that your code in GitHub,[here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-speech/samples/quickstart.rb), it is wrapped in a function. Also, this function should be called in order to be executed, you can call it by simply writing its name after the function definition. Thus the code should look as follows,

```
def quickstart
  # [START speech_quickstart]
  # Imports the Google Cloud client library
  # [START speech_ruby_migration_import]
  require "google/cloud/speech"
  # [END speech_ruby_migration_import]

  # Instantiates a client
  # [START speech_ruby_migration_client]
  speech = Google::Cloud::Speech.speech
  # [END speech_ruby_migration_client]

  # The name of the audio file to transcribe
  file_name = "./resources/brooklyn_bridge.raw"

  # [START speech_ruby_migration_sync_request]
  # [START speech_ruby_migration_config]
  # The raw audio
  audio_file = File.binread file_name

  # The audio file's encoding and sample rate
  config = { encoding:          :LINEAR16,
             sample_rate_hertz: 16_000,
             language_code:     "en-US" }
  audio  = { content: audio_file }

  # Detects speech in the audio file
  response = speech.recognize config: config, audio: audio
  # [END speech_ruby_migration_config]

  results = response.results
  # [END speech_ruby_migration_sync_request]

  # Get first result because we only processed a single audio file
  # Each result represents a consecutive portion of the audio
  results.first.alternatives.each do |alternatives|
    puts "Transcription: #{alternatives.transcript}"
  end
  # [END speech_quickstart]
end
#call the function defined above
quickstart
```

***NOTE:** I must point out that I was also able to execute the code from  your question as well, without wrapping in a function. I followed the steps described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/libraries) and it successfully retrieved the output.*

Comment: I took the code from [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/libraries). I thought I could've just used the code that was given since it worked with the text to speech version. Why is it necessary to use the 400+ lines of code in the sample you provided instead of the one that was in the link I got it from? I didn't see that when searching around in the quickstart guides from google so I thought the sample code that was given was fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Nam, you do not need to use the 400+ lines code. Within this code you can use any part of it, as I just used the part I copied in the answer. In addition, the code within the link you shared takes to the same GitHub repo, when clicking in View on GitHub. Then, you can check that the code it is wrapped within a function and after the function definition , it must be called in order to be executed.

Comment: However, I was able to use the code from GitHub and also from the link you shared (without wrapping it into a function). Please make sure you have followed all the steps described in the documentation. Also, which command are you using to execute the code? I have updated the answer with the code from GitHub, can you try with it as well and tell me if it worked?

Comment: @Nam, please consider accepting and upvoting the answer , in case you found the information useful.